# Image attached detached with custom field in Wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, custom-fields

Is it possible to use a custom field with a URL to attach the highlighted image of the post? Is there a build in function for this in Wordpress? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the WordPress `get_post_meta()` function - [source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)

using it in the loop, you can do something like

```
<img src="<?php get_post_meta($post_id, 'NEW_IMAGE', true); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what problem you are trying to solve, but it sounds you want to provide a URL to an external image instead of uploading one. I don't think this works out of the box with the default post image, but there are field plug-ins, e.g. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/ (field type picture-url).